# Woocommerce Search by Attributes

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce

I am facing a little problem with the default woocommerce search system.

I need to open a WooCommerce based Book Store. ALl The books contain unique properties like Identification No and ODN or IBN.

Now i need a search bar which gives me the result of the relative book if i enter any of the unique properties like Identification No and ODN or IBN in the search bar.

A plugin or code would work.

Thankyou very much..

Comment: Any try from your side.?

Comment: I've gone through some plugins like the YITH WooCommerce Ajax Search and Woocommerce Product Finder but both of these add filters to attributes like you chose between the color red, yellow or blue but this isnt beneficial because i cannot add all the unique attributes to the filter. What's the point if i add all the unique identification numbers to a filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution I hope it helps to the people to who are facing the same issue.

I have found a plugin by the name SearchWP. It is really an extensive search plugin. It supports WooCommerce and also supports custom fields.I can also weight to attributes which are saved as meta fields to sort the search. Here is a video that gives you an overview of the plugin:

[SearchWP](https://youtu.be/7TW1sHWo7YQ)

Comment: does anyone knows a PHP coding solution instead of getting a plugin?