# Display product in search results by single variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have product variations with size and color attributes that have separate stock and SKU.

In my search result I want to show only the product with the color attribute.

There is a way that the search results will group the variations (color and size) and display the product only with the product and the color attribute?

example:
i have yellow shoes with diffrents size (45,46,68), each color and size is varaition.

in the filter results i want to display only the product with the color (i dont want that the customer will show same shoes in the same color but with diffrent size). i need to group the size-color variations and to display only color varition.

im using the yith woocommerce ajax filter plugin.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: Use this plugin https://searchwp.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce Search by Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464453/woocommerce-search-by-attributes)

Comment: @MukeshPanchal -  i have diffrent problem - ). i need to group the size-color variations and to display only color varition Although hvae size-color variation

Comment: @gwesseling - i treid WooCommerce Show Single Variations plugin - but if i want to achive this i need to do a workaround - "Hey, yes it can – just choose one size of each colour to show, and disable the “Add to Cart” button."

Comment: Hey, I've added some more advanced logic to WooCommerce Show Single Variations now for displaying one of each color: https://docs.iconicwp.com/article/54-show-only-one-of-each-colour-or-other-attribute-in-the-catalog